# Why is there an issue with substituting matrices into sympy nested commutators?

Tags: matrix, sympy, symbolic-math

I am using the Commutator class from sympy.physics.quantum and ran into an issue calculating nested commutators of matrices. For some reason, I find that substituting matrices for symbols and then evaluating the commutator expression with `expression.doit()` produces a zero matrix (which is incorrect). On the other hand, if I expand the commutator expressions and then substitute matrices for the symbols, I get the correct answer. Why does this occur?

The following code reproduces the error:

```
import sympy as sp

tau_1, tau_2, tau_3 = sp.symbols('tau_1 tau_2 tau_3')
A = sp.symbols("A", commutative=False, cls=sp.Function)(tau_1)
B = sp.symbols("B", commutative=False, cls=sp.Function)(tau_2)
C = sp.symbols("C", commutative=False, cls=sp.Function)(tau_3)

matrix_from_symbol = {
        A: sp.Matrix([[sp.sin(tau_1),sp.sin(tau_1)],[sp.sin(tau_1),1+sp.sin(tau_1)]]),
        B: sp.Matrix([[sp.sin(tau_2),sp.sin(tau_2)],[sp.sin(tau_2),1+sp.sin(tau_2)]]),
        C: sp.Matrix([[sp.sin(tau_3),sp.sin(tau_3)],[sp.sin(tau_3),1+sp.sin(tau_3)]])
}

from sympy.physics.quantum import Commutator

expression = Commutator(A,Commutator(B,C))
doit_then_subs = expression.doit().subs(matrix_from_symbol,simultaneous=True).simplify()
sp.pprint(doit_then_subs) #gives a non-zero matrix; correct answer

subs_then_doit = expression.subs(matrix_from_symbol,simultaneous=True).doit()
sp.pprint(subs_then_doit) #gives a zero matrix
```

Comment: Your question might be better if you showed some results, not only the prints, but also the `expression.doit()` etc.  Only an expert can run this code in their head, and thus visualize what's happening.  That said, I tested  your code in a ipython session, and looked at various results.  For a single non-nested commutator that two approaches match.  But I don't know enough of what's implemented in the commutator class to know why the nested case doesn't work.  But I'm not surprised that there are limitations on what a construct like this can do.

Comment: I want to print the results but I am unsure of how to do this without rendering some latex (which I believe stack overflow doesn't use). I'll see if I can find another way to print the result, then update the question. Also, yes you're correct that a single commutator works just fine @hpaulj

Comment: I looked at the Commutator code.  It's a rather simple subclass of `Expr`, primarily adding the `doit` which expands it, as documented into `A*B-B*A`.  It not override `subs`.

Comment: Look at `expression.subs(matrix_from_symbol,simultaneous=True)`.  This is the 'raw' result of doing the `subs`, and which `doit` reduces to the 0 matrix.

Comment: @hpaulj I agree about the 'raw' result of doing subs, but the expression looks fine to me. Furthermore, if I use 'raw'.simplify() it properly evaluates the commutator, and another .simplify() gives the correct simplified expression. For some reason, .doit() seems to be an issue. I'll take a look at the source code.

Comment: My guess is that `doit` is pretty complicated.  Also this may be more of an issue with `Matrix` or nested `Matrix`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that sympy does not perform matrix multiplication when evaluating `A.subs(matrix_from_symbols,simultaneous=True) * Commutator(B,C).subs(matrix_from_symbol,simultaneous=True).` Instead, it appears to treat the `Commutator(B,C)` as a scalar, producing the following result:

```
⎡        ⎡⎡sin(τ₂)    sin(τ₂)  ⎤ ⎡sin(τ₃)    sin(τ₃)  ⎤⎤             ⎡⎡sin(τ₂)
⎢sin(τ₁)⋅⎢⎢                    ⎥,⎢                    ⎥⎥     sin(τ₁)⋅⎢⎢       
⎢        ⎣⎣sin(τ₂)  sin(τ₂) + 1⎦ ⎣sin(τ₃)  sin(τ₃) + 1⎦⎦             ⎣⎣sin(τ₂)
⎢                                                                             
⎢        ⎡⎡sin(τ₂)    sin(τ₂)  ⎤ ⎡sin(τ₃)    sin(τ₃)  ⎤⎤                ⎡⎡sin(
⎢sin(τ₁)⋅⎢⎢                    ⎥,⎢                    ⎥⎥  (sin(τ₁) + 1)⋅⎢⎢    
⎣        ⎣⎣sin(τ₂)  sin(τ₂) + 1⎦ ⎣sin(τ₃)  sin(τ₃) + 1⎦⎦                ⎣⎣sin(

    sin(τ₂)  ⎤ ⎡sin(τ₃)    sin(τ₃)  ⎤⎤   ⎤
             ⎥,⎢                    ⎥⎥   ⎥
  sin(τ₂) + 1⎦ ⎣sin(τ₃)  sin(τ₃) + 1⎦⎦   ⎥
                                         ⎥
τ₂)    sin(τ₂)  ⎤ ⎡sin(τ₃)    sin(τ₃)  ⎤⎤⎥
                ⎥,⎢                    ⎥⎥⎥
τ₂)  sin(τ₂) + 1⎦ ⎣sin(τ₃)  sin(τ₃) + 1⎦⎦⎦
```

To see that this is the case, I also tried `sp.Matmul(A.subs(matrix_from_symbol,simultaneous=True),Commutator(B,C).subs(matrix_from_symbol,simultaneous=True))`

which throws the error message: `"noncommutative scalars in MatMul are not supported"` 
Until the Commutator class is updated to work with matrices, one workaround is to use noncommutative symbols in commutators, evaluate the commutators with `.doit()`, then substitute matrices into the final expression.

Thanks to @hpaulj for helpful comments and suggestions (especially regarding looking at the source code)